# Relative resource paths in Java project in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am trying to display an icon in my GUI by using a relative path, as in "display image from `resources/image.png`". I have tried a million different ways to express this, but nothing works. This makes me think it's a problem with my IntelliJ IDEA settings or project structure. I have set up the "resources" folder as a "resources folder". I don't know what else it expects me to do.

**How can I load an icon from a file using a relative path in a Java project within IntelliJ IDEA?**

My project structure:

```
src/main/java/ <-- set as "sources" in IntelliJ
src/main/java/ui/ <-- contains classes for my GUI
src/main/resources/ <-- set as "resources" in IntelliJ. Contains images.
```

Edit: Able to use relative path to confirm that file is found, not able to load it as icon.

```
String path = "src/main/resources/image.png";
System.out.println(new File(path).exists()); <-- true
```

Comment: how are you loading the images in code? I feel like this may have nothing to do with IntelliJ

Comment: Well, one of the ways I've tried is from here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html

Comment: try to use [`ImageIO`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html) which was made for convenient image loading (e.g. `ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream(path)))`

Comment: although, the way the tutorial does it _should_ work, but I doubt it's an IntelliJ issue as loading images from a relative path works for me with no modifications. what is your project's directory structure?

Comment: @AtteJuvonen Could you give your complete project structure, for you might have `resources` in the incorrect place

Comment: @1blustone That code snippet gives `IllegalArgumentException: input == null!` with all variations of path.

Comment: I edited project structure into OP now.

Comment: @AtteJuvonen In which `directory` is the class where you want to add this `code` ?

Comment: @Shashwat `src/main/java/ui`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've encountered this issue many times and what worked for me was using `InputStream`

```
InputStream is = Main.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("name_of_file.png");
```

Using `InputStream` will allow you read from various file types. Now to load in the icon you can do

```
Icon icon = new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(is));
```

Comment: this is suppose to refer to the class you can also call `Main.class.*` where `Main` is the name of your class

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133158/discussion-between-coletrain-and-atte-juvonen).

Answer (score 0):

Resources are on classpath, not on filesystem path  - which is taken relative from running directory, which is project directory when you are running it from idea.  Usually you will distribute your aplication  as jar, and this it is better to load resources from classpath.  In zour case -  from root directory